# Make GameObject Move Towards Direction It Is Facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

How do I make my GameObject move towards the way it is facing when using rigidbody.velocity?

```
private void PlayerInput()
{
    _xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    _zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    _xMouseInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity;
}

private void PlayerMovement()
{
    _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(_xInput, _rigidbody.velocity.y, _zInput) * _playerSpeed;
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * _xMouseInput);
}
```

Comment: You may multiply the Vector3 with transform.forward.

Comment: See AddRelativeForce.